Aprilaire Model 56 Gen 1 humidstat not picking up solenoid valve in TEST mode
I have an Aprilaire model 600M humidifier with a model 56 Gen 1 humidistat. Getting 24vac to power terminals of humidistat. A/A terminals from humidistat going directly to the solenoid valve. Solenoid valve and water supply checked out OK because when I supply 24VAC directly to solenoid valve I get water flowing through the humidifier. There is a "Manual Mode" Resister in place of outdoor sensor. When humidistat in TEST position, not picking up solenoid. I am assuming that the A/A terminals should supply 24VAC directly to the solenoid when humidity is required but in TEST mode and furnace heat and blower operational, but I am not getting any voltage from humidistat. Assuming wiring is proper, how should I check out this system and humidistat to make sure it is functional?
